# Integer value error Python write file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to build a script that would scan through a website, create a time stamped folder, and then drop time-stamped files into the folder. I was able to get the script to scan through the website and make the time stamped files, however when I try to get a dynamically named folder I get an error. I have posted the working code with the broken code commented out. I am not sure what to do, any suggestions are welcome.

```
ValueError: mode string must begin with one of 'r', 'w', 'a' or 'U', not
'dataC1-07-28-2013.csv'
```

This is the code, the non-working code is commented out:

```
import urllib2
import datetime
#import os

today = datetime.date.today()
todayDate = today.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

#newpath = '/home/blah/Data ' + todayDate
#if not os.path.exists(newpath): os.makedirs(newpath)

print "starting load for", todayDate

stub = "http://website.ashx?v=151&c="
for i in range(1, 66):
    print "getting", i, "..."
    data = urllib2.urlopen(stub + str(i)).read()
    f = open("fooC" + str(i) + "-" + todayDate +".csv", "w")
#   f = open('newpath',"fooC" + str(i) + "-" + todayDate +".csv", "w")
    f.write(data)
    f.close()

print "load complete!"
```

Comment: Only the commented out code can cause that error. Are you certain you re-ran your script?

Comment: I'm getting the feeling you think passing multiple arguments to `open` will join them together, it doesn't. You need to join the directory and filename together manually with `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build an *absolute* path, preferably using [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
f = open(os.path.join('newpath', "fooC" + str(i) + "-" + todayDate +".csv"), "w")
```

`open()` does not take separate directory and filename arguments, the second argument is the `mode` argument, always.

Comment: Thank you! I should have dug a bit more into open() before posting, sorry for the pretty useless question. One thing is that I had to remove the ' ' around newpath otherwise tries to make a directory called newpath/foo instead of using the previously defined path.

Answer (score 1):

In your commented out open you input three arguments whereas it takes only two (docs to be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)): the filename and the mode in which to open it (read, write etc.).

In order to open a file in a new subdirectory you have to use os.path.join to get the file (you can read more on how it works [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)). An example:

```
with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "w") as f:
    #Here do what you want with the file
```

Hope this helps. Also opening a file in a with block is a bit safer than just opening it like that far as I can tell.